# Get value in input while iterating over table to make array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, html-table

I have a table where the last two `<td>` tags in each row have text inputs. I am trying to dump the table into an array to then make a csv.

Code that converts table to array:

```
$("table#results-table tr").each(function() {
var arrayOfThisRow = [];
var tableData = $(this).find('td');
if (tableData.length > 0) {
    tableData.each(function() {
      arrayOfThisRow.push($(this).text());
    });
    tableArray.push(arrayOfThisRow);
}
});
```

this will return the items with just text, but not the data in the inputs. I assume this has to do with the `$(this).text()` but I cannot figure out how to fix it.

Comment: Did you try `.html()` or `.val()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `input` is inside `td` and if there is only 1 `input` inside that `td` then

`$(this).find('input').val()`

will get you the values from input field